# LARAVEL 5.0 + Unit Test - assertSessionHasErrors with different bags

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel-5, laravel-validation, laravel-request

I am writing a unit test in Laravel 5.0 and in my request class I am using a different bag to show the validation error messages.

I am using this in my file:

```
/* ExampleRequest.php */
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class ExampleRequest extends Request {

    protected $errorBag = 'otherbag';

    public function rules(){
        return [
            'my_field' => 'required'
        ];
    }
}
```

In my test file, I am testing using this:

```
/* ExampleTest.php */
class ExampleTest extends TestCase {
    public function testPostWithoutData(){
        $response = $this->call('POST', 'url/to/post',[
            'my_field' => ''
        ]);
        $this->assertSessionHasErrors('my_field');
    }
}
```

If I run the tests, it can't get the right assert and return this problem:

> Session missing error: `my_field`
>   Failed asserting that `false` is `true`.

If I take out the `$errorBag` attribute from the request file, I have no problems.

I can give more details as needed.

Comment: Can you explain why you have `protected $errorBag = 'otherbag';` in your object? What does this do and why?

Comment: Because I have two places to show erros im my view... And i handle it with different bags....

Answer (score 2):

You can get an alternate bag from the session store like this:

```
$myBag = $this->app('session_store')->getBag('otherBag');
$this->assertTrue($myBag->any());
```

However, Laravel does not use an alternate bag by default, so I'm assuming you're doing something in your code to register your `App\Request::$errorBag` with the session handler.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are setting your session elsewhere but I guess you may do something like:

`$this->session(['foo' => 'bar']);`

Before you can assert something in session. [See testing helpers section for Laravel 5.0](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/testing#helper-methods)